# How do you pass an argument variable while to an imported script?

Tags: python, variables, argv

I have two scripts. Script A has a bunch of functions with variables in them, that need to be defined in Script B.

For example, this is basically what I need to do in script A and B

A.py:

```
health = {p1:"100", p2:"100"}
```

The rest of the script requires that dictionary to be defined.

B.py:

```
p1 = raw_input()
p2 = raw_input()
from A.py import *

#Here, I get the error that p1 and p2 aren't defined in A.py
#I need to pass p1 and p2 (in B.py) to the health dict in A.py
```

How do I pass an argument variable to an imported script?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a function in `A.py` to pass the values into:

```
def DoStuff(p1, p2):
  #work with dict here
```

Side note: Don't use strings for clearly numerical values like player health.